# Do we see planet venus everyday?

Tags: venus

Do we see planet Venus every day? (Just before sun sets or Just after sun sets) throughout year? or some days we don't see it?

Answer (score 7):

No. Some days Venus is an evening star, visible for up to a few hours after the Sun sets. Some days it is a morning star, visible for a few hours before the Sun rises. Some days it is so close to the Sun in the sky that we can't see it at all (or even actually behind the Sun).

Venus can also be seen in daylight, if it is above the horizon, not too close to the Sun and the sky is clear. You need to know where to look for it, though, it's only a little brighter than the sky.

Comment: FWIW, a few years ago, Venus was close to its maximum brightness and very close to the Moon, so it was easy to locate. I was fortunate to have clear skies all day and I was able to see Venus with the naked eye every hour of that day, even though my eyes aren't as sharp as they were 4 or 5 decades ago. I must admit that I have spent a lot of time trying to spot Venus before sunset, and I guess that helped.

Comment: @PM2Ring you could see Venus at midday? Were you in a spaceship? ;-)

Comment: @Chappo Yes, I saw Venus at midday. At that time I was at home, on the mid-north coast of New South Wales, Australia. An hour or so later I was at the beach, and I saw Venus from there, too.

Comment: I'm impressed! You realise I will now have to scan the skies tomorrow - weather permitting - to see if I can spot it! I think it's close to maximum brightness at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Venus goes through a 19 month synodic cycle as seen from Earth, roughly:

- 8 months as an evening star
- 1 month passing in front of the Sun
- 8 months as a morning star
- 2 months passing behind the Sun

In any given month, Venus can be an evening star all month, be a morning star all month, be too close to the Sun, or pass from one state to the next.